# Heads should roll

Tags: phrase-meaning

I understand the phrase "Heads should roll" as "Some people should be punished."  Am I on the right track?

> **Heads should roll**: LSU students react to investigation.

> Heads should roll: LSU students want school to fire those implicated by investigative report

> Source: [USAToday](https://www.usatoday.com/story/news/investigations/2021/03/05/lsu-students-want-school-fire-those-implicated-investigation/4599499001/)

Comment: Yes, you are on the right track. If a beheading is done with enough vim and vigor, the detached head can roll along the ground for a yard or two. It is refreshing to see young adults recognize the deterrent effect of public executions.

Answer (score 1):

You are indeed on the right track—specifically, it is saying that the people responsible should be *severely* punished (often, as in this case, fired).

The standard form of this idiom is "heads will roll," [defined by Merriam Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/heads%20will%20roll) as

> used to say that people will be severely punished or will lose their jobs because of something that has happened
>
> *When the boss finds out about the mistake, heads will roll.*

It is an allusion to someone's head literally rolling on the ground after a beheading (one [source](https://www.phrases.org.uk/meanings/heads-will-roll.html)).  In modern English usage, it is much less literal: in most cases where this phrase would be used, an actual beheading would not be expected.